# Ruby on Rails, multiple requests delay

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails app deployed on Heroku. It has "Item" model, in "create" action some data is being processed (text analysis, sometimes huge texts), and this process takes a long time. If another request comes to the web server it takes too long to load any page. What is the best way to avoid such delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a situation like this, you would typically use a background job manager like [DelayedJob](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) or [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque).  If you're just starting out, I'd recommend playing with DJ as it's quite simple to set up and does not require any external dependencies.

Since you've mentioned Heroku, they have a nice write up [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job) on how to get it started with your app.

Essentially, you would take long-running tasks and add them to a job queue (in DJ's case, just another table in your database), where another process will monitor that table and run jobs as they appear. This way, you can return a response to your user immediately while the job is being worked in the background, keeping your web dyno free to handle requests concurrently.

If you're on Heroku, then you would need to pay for a worker dyno to run alongside your web dyno.

Also it depends on your server setup. If you were using an application server like Unicorn, you should be able to run multiple Rails processes within a single dyno, so you can still handle web requests even if one is tied up doing your text analysis.

But in all honesty, it sounds like your app isn't quite ready to run in production on Heroku anyway, as this issue should have already had a solution in place before you even deployed there.  You don't want to keep web processes tied up doing work that may be better suited for a background worker process.